# How to access a variable of method of an another class?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Actually I am working on a project in which I have to access a variable of a method of another class and facing a similar kind of situation in my project I can not return that value. Please, anyone, solve this problem.

```
package com.company;

class aaa {
    int num1;
    public void val() { // data type can't be changed
        num1 = 100;
    }
}

class  bbb {
    public void Values() {
        int num = 100;
    }
}

public class Main extends bbb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        aaa obj1 = new aaa();
        bbb abj2 = new bbb();
        System.out.println(obj1.num1); // wants to print value 100 here but 
                                      //without returning value from the function

    }
}
```

Comment: *FYI:* You may want to check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: This is simply impossible. The variables of a method only exist while a method is running. Even if the method was on the call stack, you wouldn't be able to access the variable. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The `local` variable num1 is just that, local. It was created in the method so the scope is that of the method. You need to create a class member called num1. If num1 is public you can reference it the way you want. If the member is private you need a getter. If you want to return the value you need to change the `signature` from `void` to `int`.

**I don't condone any of this naming, just keeping it simple.**

```java
public class AAA {
    private int num1;

    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }
}
```

```java
obj1.getNum1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once this variable is in method scope, it's not possible. The only way to do what you need is by creating a variable in the class scope. I wouldn't do something like that, but create the variable as private and the get and set methods instead.

```
package com.company;
class  aaa{

    public int num1;

    public void val(){
        num1 = 100;
    }
}
class  bbb{
    public void Values(){
        int num = 100;
    }
}
public class Main extends bbb{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        aaa obj1 = new aaa();
        bbb abj2 = new bbb();
        System.out.println(obj1.num1); // now the variable is in public access

    }
}
```